# Need to assign feature value of A annotation to B based on some condition -uima ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

Annotation A has 3 features namely, name, date & index.
Annotation B has 3 features namely, name, date & index.
Values are assigned to all the features except B.index. Matching name & date of A & B, I want to assign A.index to B.index

**Sample output:**

```
A annotaion:

   Wardlaw
      name:Wardlaw
      date:2003
      index:3
   Rahul
       name:Rahul
       date:1993
       index:4


B annotaion:

   Rahul
       name:Rahul
       date:1993
       index:0

   Wardlaw
       name:Wardlaw
       date:2003
       index:0
```

Expected Output:

B annotaion:

```
   Rahul
       name:Rahul
       date:1993
       index:4

   Wardlaw
       name:Wardlaw
       date:2003
       index:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
a:A{a.name == b.name, a.date == b.date} # b:@B{ -> b.index = a.index};
```

I put the anchor on `B` so that no B is missed. The condition need to be placed at `A` so that the wildcard stops at the correct annotation.

If the `A`s and the `B`s share the same offset, you need another, simpler rule with only one rule element and no wildcard..

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*